# HIVEQL - how to write condition for JSON values

Tags: json, hiveql

I have the following data in one of the table I exported from dynamoDB:

```
...
SUID{
    "s": {\"profileElementType\":\"1\",\"version\":0,\"seq\":1,\"sUid\":\"15141\"}"
}
OPTED{
    "s": "{\"profileElementType\":\"2\",\"version\":0,\"seq\":4,\"value\":\"1\"}"
...
```

I created the hive table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA_FULL (item map<string, string> )
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "ORIGINAL_DATA");
```

I wanted to understand how to write the WHERE clause in HiveQL to process such data.

I tried the following HiveQL:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_FULL where item['SUID'] LIKE '%15141%';
```

No results.

```
SELECT item['SUID'],item['OPTED'] FROM DATA_FULL where   
(item['OPTED'] LIKE '%\"value\":\"0\"%' or item['OPTED'] LIKE   
'%\"value\":\"2\"%');
```

No Results (The HiveQL above tries to 
 extract values from this table that has OPTED like "Value:0" or OPTED like "Value:2"

Answer (score 0):

Changed the WHERE clause and added one more \ to the conditions.

```
 SELECT item['SUID'],item['OPTED'] FROM DATA_FULL where   
 (item['OPTED'] LIKE '%\\"value\\":\\"0\\"%');
```